# How can I replace the `application:adapter` with a `DS.FixtureAdapter` in my acceptance tests?

Tags: ember.js

We're using Ember Data and have a `RestAdapter`, but we don't want to use this in our tests. 
How can I replace the `application:adapter` with a `DS.FixtureAdapter` in my acceptance tests?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to re-register it in the container.

```
App.__container__.register('adapter:application', DS.FixtureAdapter);
```

And depending on how you run your tests, you might be able to put in directly in the App namespace if you're calling `App.reset()`.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

Comment: unfortunately none of those work:  register does nothing and the App doesn't expose ApplicationAdapter

Comment: You might need to call `unregister` first. It's hard to pinpoint your problem though. Could you elaborate a bit on how you're testing the application? Maybe give a sample test?

Comment: the application is using EmberApp Kit, the tests are exactly the same as here: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit-todos/blob/master/tests/acceptance/todos_test.js The main difference is in that project they are using FixtureAdapter from the beginning, so they don't have to switch

Comment: Ahh, Ember-App-Kit. Can't say I know very much about how the resolver works. But in this file (https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit-todos/blob/master/tests/helpers/module-for.js), it shows registering the FixtureAdapter. Maybe you could modify that function to look for the correct adapter from configuration instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know it, the problem is that function is creating it's own isolated container, not using the one from the application.